# Where is the implementation of System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.Dispose()?

Tags: .net, reflector, .net-reflector

I am using Reflector but I can't find System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.Dispose(). Where is it?

Comment: Maybe in one of the base classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on `ServiceHostBase`.  It's explicitly implemented so you're looking for the name `System.IDisposable.Dispose` instead of simply `Dispose`